# Meteor Useraccounts. How to add name field and store it under profile.name

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, meteor-accounts

I am using the Useraccounts package. I added a field called 'name' so user can enter name on sign up and sign in. But I want to store its value like this in the profile field

```
profile.name: "user"
```

NOT default

```
name: "user"
```

Also can I call Accounts.onCreateUser function on the server when using Useraccount? And hopefully change it there? Sorry about the noob question but any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Accounts.onCreateUser()` on the server. This function takes an `options` object. Assuming you have:

```
options.profile.name = 'user';
```

when you create the account then you can do:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
})
```

And that addition to the profile key will make it into the actual user doc.

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined" exception from ATCreateUserServer method.

Comment: Sorry, had incorrectly assumed profile would already exist. See correction.

Comment: Then just do `user.profile={}; user.profile.name=options.name;`